# What's the difference between hypsography and topography?

Tags: elevation, topology, topography

I've recently come across some data that has been labeled "hypsography". I looked it up and it sounds like topography. But this data source has data labeled "topography" separate from its "hypsography". What's the difference?

I've read the wiki for 'Elevation' and its starting to sound like all the "topos" I've been reading are really "hypsos"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Hypsography** concerns the land's elevation, altitude or height above sea-level or some other reference surface. (*Hypso* is derived from the Greek *Ύψος* for height.)

**Topography** concerns physical and cultural features of the land and so includes hypsography, hydrology, the built environment, major boundaries, communication channels, etc. (*Topo* is derived from the Greek *Τόπος* for place.)

Note, however, that North Americans often (incorrectly) use "topography" when they mean only "elevation" (or "hypsography").

Answer (score 3):

Hypsography can be used to describe the **elevation** of the land as it's related to other areas (ie, mean sea level).

Topography can be used to describe the **features** on that elevated land and also how they are related (ie, their spatial relationship) to each other.

Answer (score -2):

Hypsography deals with the peak heights or one can say spot heights from which we derive heights after completion of top maps

Answer (score -2):

The altitude ,steepness and direction of slope of land is called its topograhy. It modifies environmental factors, radiation , temprature and moisture contents. So topography indirectly influence the orgonsim