# Changing slopes derived from DEM using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, slope, simulation

I have a DEM for a region over which I want to simulate an ecological process.  I would like to run several simulations for the same region but I want to alter the topography for the simulations.  Most important, I would like to alter the slope (and probably aspect) in various ways.  I am working in ArcGIS Desktop and I extracted the slope from the DEM but I have not found any way to manipulate the slope or even access the slope values with their coordinates.  Running the process requires several other layers so I would like to remain within the parameters (coordinates, datum, ellipsoid, etc.) of the original DEM.

Is there a way I can alter the slope output, which is currently a raster?

Could I, for example, make the whole region 30% slope with a south aspect?

Is there some other way to generate custom slope files that will be consistent with the other layers?

I am using an ArcGRID DEM from the NED.

Perhaps a different starting point is more appropriate, such as a contour map?

Comment: Why do you wish to change the slope values you already have? Is there a possibility of some wholesale re-landscaping?

Comment: I think you mean "hypsography", rather than "topography". See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76309/whats-the-difference-between-hypsography-and-topography/76342#76342

Answer (score 4):

A contour map is rarely a good starting point, especially if you already have a (gridded) elevation model. Contours are cartographic, rather than topographic, features.

Having said that, if the DEM was *derived* from a contour map to begin with, then maybe you *should* return to the source.